How to shutdown Go server that running in Docker container gracefully?
Now, a web server written in Go is running in docker container.
When stopping docker container executing docker stop command, I want to shutdown the web server gracefully.
In this case, is it possible to perform graceful shutdown like the following?

current code

ctx, stop := signal.NotifyContext(context.Background(), syscall.SIGTERM) // I don't know what signal to catch
defer stop()

srv := &http.Server{
    Addr:    port,
    Handler: mux,
}

go srv.ListenAndServe()

<-ctx.Done()

// do someshing

log.Println("server will shutdown gracefully.")

err = srv.Shutdown(ctx)
if err != nil {
    return err
}




Documentation for which signals docker container stop sends by default, and how to override them if you need: https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/container/stop/

There are also a couple of subtleties around Dockerfile setup to correctly receive SIGTERM.  Does the code you show work without Docker?  What does your Dockerfile look like?  How are you invoking the container?

Your code looks fine, and should work. docker container stop first sends SIGTERM, then some time later, SIGKILL. Mind that some contents of the syscall package are implementation-specific, so what's there for GOOS=windows may be missing for GOOS=linux etc.

@Zyl Isn't the context already "done" when reused for src.Shutdown?

@MarkusWMahlberg You're right. I was too focused on OP asking about what signal to listen for.

SIGTERM is the correct signal to listen for. There are however a couple of improvements that can be made to your code.

Don't ignore the return value of ListenAndServe() (which likely will be context.Canceled, but does not have to be).
Don't supply an already canceled context to Shutdown(). We are going to be subjected to SIGKILL (a signal which we won't actually receive) if this takes too much time, so we can just supply context.Background().
Use a sync.WaitGroup to prevent log messages from being out of order.

This gives us the following:
ctx, stop := signal.NotifyContext(context.Background(), syscall.SIGTERM)

srv := &http.Server{
    Addr:    port,
    Handler: mux,
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(1)
go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    defer stop() // if context did not get canceled, cancel it so we don't block below
    err := srv.ListenAndServe()
    log.Printf("ListenAndServe() returned: %v", err)
}()

<-ctx.Done()
log.Println("server will shutdown gracefully.") // if ListenAndServe() already returned, this is a lie; consider rephrasing
err := srv.Shutdown(context.Background())

wg.Wait() // ensure go-routine returns from log.Printf() before anything else happens
return err

The important takeaway is that Shutdown() will patiently wait on active connections, which may or may not finish in time. It is possible to make use of signal.NotifyContext() in the handlers as well, to try and finish remaining work up quickly in case that SIGTERM is received. I suggest to rather supply an appropriate --time argument to docker container stop instead (in case the default of 10 seconds is insufficient).

My 2 cents: I'd also listen for SIGINT, which more often than not translates to Ctrl+X. Waiting indefinitely for the server to shutdown is probably not the best idea. And third, I'd rather put the LaS call into main and handle the shutdown behavior in a goroutine. See https://go.dev/play/p/u4-04M6YcDq

@MarkusWMahlberg If I understand Shutdown() correctly, it will first cause ListenAndServe() to return, meaning your code could return from main() before your go-routine returns from Shutdown(). Do we know if cancelling the context of Shutdown() is any less critical than receiving SIGKILL?

SIGKILL should not be handled, imho - it is used to unconditionally terminate a process. As for Shutdown() -  that could only happen in case we have no connections to wait for. However, now that you mentioned it, that heavily depends on how defer is actually implemented. The signal handler can only intercept the signals when the goroutine is already running. Also, the cancel is only pro forma, since ctxholds no resources. Also, tasks that absolutely MUST be executed can be run in RegisterOnShutdown.
